# How can I avoid a function name clash while implementing a trait?

Tags: rust, private, traits

I have a struct with an implementation that has a function which accesses the private state of the struct.

```
struct Example {...}

impl Example {
    fn test(&self) -> .. {...}
}
```

Somewhere else in another module there exists another trait:

```
trait ExampleTrait {
    fn test(&self) -> .. {...}
}
```

Now I would like to implement `ExampleTrait` for the `Example` struct and to forward the test method to the test `impl` for the struct.

The following code:

```
impl ExampleTrait for Example {
    fn test(&self) -> .. {
        self.test()
    }
}
```

Is obviously an infinite recursive call. I cannot just repeat the body of the original test as I do not have access to the private state of `Example` here.

Is there another way to do this except for renaming one function or making fields in `Example` public?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [fully-qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation) to disambiguate which method is to be used:

```
impl ExampleTrait for Example {
    fn test(&self) {
        Example::test(self) // no more ambiguity
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to avoid adding this method stub completely? for instance if a trait has 10 functions which are already derived from another macro/trait, how can I avoid adding this boiler plate? (in other words just add a `impl SomeTrait for MyType {// leave empty since function names coincide and are already implemented}`